# Execution failed for task 'app:mergeReleaseResources' in react native while building release apk

Tags: android, react-native

I have a running react native app but when I try to build release APK with the command `gradlew assembleRelease`

It shows the following error:

[image]

I have tried

```
android {
  aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
  aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false }
```

and setting `android.enableAapt2=false` but nothing worked. I have also replaced the res folder. But still the same result. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the Gradle version you're using?

Comment: i'm using gradle 4.6 @whd.nsr

Answer (score 0):

There many causes of this issue, but try to unify build tool version and SDK version for all Android project modules. you can do that by putting this code on the `build.gradle` file on the project level.

```
subprojects {
project.configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "28.0.0"
        }
    }
}
afterEvaluate {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            targetSdkVersion 28
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3fk4bo?embed=1&file=index.js  But it shows the error that compileSdkVersion not specified. @whd.nsr

Comment: I think you added it in a wrong place.
Add it inside android/build.gradle file